# Find Minimum Distance between two variables in R

Tags: r

I want to find the row with minimum distance between the X and Y, and return the corresponding Z in R. Table 3 shows an example of this.

Table 1

```
X       Z
10      0.655883255
20      0.511846995
10.5    0.995310138
```

Table 2

```
Y
11
12
13.5
23
```

Table 3

```
X       Z
11      0.99
12      0.99
13.5    0.99
23      0.511
```

Comment: Table 3 are you sure it is `X` and `Z` the column names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you have to have this in a table format, but easy enough if they're vectors.

```
x <- c(10, 20, 10.5)
z <- c(0.655883255, 0.511846995, 0.995310138)
y <- c(11, 12, 13.5, 23)
z[unlist(lapply(y, function(t) which.min(abs(x-t))))]

# [1] 0.9953101 0.9953101 0.9953101 0.5118470
```